# Quintic Polynomials and finding the fifth root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have a quintic Polynomial that I am having trouble finding the fifth root.

I have -8, 7, -3, and 1 as roots

The leading coefficient is -9

coefficient of $x^4$ is 9

I think it is 4 however, I'm having difficultly with the formula to find the fifth root.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use 1. Vieta formula:

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5= -{b\over a}$$

where polynomial $$ax^5+bx^4+....$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(x-7)(x-1) (x+3)(x+8) ( x - A) = x^5 + (3-A)x^4 - (3A + 57)x^3 + (57A - 115)x^2 + (115A + 168)x - 168A $$

Comment: Sorry, it should state that the leading coefficient is -9

Comment: Hi there Will Jagy, can you please elaborate as to how you expanded this, and do you then solve for A?